# Magento 2 add mobile number to checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, mobile

I have created mobile number as customer attribute by this code

```
    $customerSetup -> addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
        'mobile',
        [
        'label' => 'Mobile Number',
        'system' => 0,
        'position' => 100,
        'sort_order' =>100,
        'visible' =>  true,
        'note' => 'this item used for login',


                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'input' => 'text',

        ]
        );

    $customerSetup -> getEavConfig() -> getAttribute('customer', 'mobile')->setData('is_user_defined',1)->setData('is_required',1)->setData('default_value','')->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'checkout_register', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'adminhtml_checkout']) -> save();
```

But I cannot see the mobile number in checkout.

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: have you checked this attribute in eav_attribute table and admin end customer section?

Comment: yeah ... i see it and i use for login by mobile but in checkout i can not see @NagarajuKasa

Comment: are you needed checkout page under shipping and billing address right?

Comment: yes ... i need show mobile if customer are guest or registered

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html) you find information how to add new custom field into checkout shipping address. In similar way you can do it for Billing Address.

Unfortunately devdocs doesn't have information how to save new field from checkout in database.

Shipping address is saved in Quote when you switch from step 1 to step 2. Billing address is saved in Quote when you make a order. Then addresses from Quote details are saved in Customer object.

You have to check the core and override some methods (or use plugins for it)

There are many ways to do it, but remember that all datas are saved in Quote first, so you have to extend also the Quote.

Comment: thanks ...my problem for now is The customer attribute could shown on shipping address ?

Comment: In link what I paste here you have a info how to show a new field on shipping address